# Installed but appears ModuleNotFoundError: No Module named 'requests'

Tags: python

I installed ''requests'' but this error is still appearing, what can it be?

[ImageError](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7JdkE.png)

Comment: What command did you use to install requests, and what command did you use to run this script?

Comment: Hey, welcome to asking on SO! Could you provide the output of installing the requests module on the command prompt? Also, when you do could you copy and paste it into your question rather than send an image? It makes it much easier to read.

Comment: I used the command ''pip install requests''

Comment: When I used the command ''python -m pip install requests'' it appeared ''Requirement already satisfied'' | When I used the command ''python3 -m pip install requests'' it appeared ''Requirement already satisfied''

Answer (score 1):

Try: `python -m pip install requests` (or `python3 -m pip install requests` for python3)

Comment: When I used the command ''python -m pip install requests'' it appeared ''Requirement already satisfied'' | When I used the command ''python3 -m pip install requests'' it appeared ''Requirement already satisfied''

Comment: It is possible that it needs an upgrade
Use : 
pip install requests --upgrade